# LazyColumn doesn't updates

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

My dataset undergoes multiple changes during program execution. However, the LazyColumn fails to reflect these changes and doesn't add the updated items.

in the main activity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    companion object {
        var myDataset = mutableListOf<MyNotification>()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NotyTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val dbHelper = MyDatabaseHelper(this)
                    val db = dbHelper.readableDatabase
                    myDataset = readDB(db)
                    
                    MyApp(dataset = myDataset)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(dataset: MutableList<MyNotification>) {
    val notifications = remember { dataset }

    LazyColumn {
        items(
            items = notifications,
            itemContent = { 
                NotificationItem(notification = it)
            })
    }
}

@Composable
fun NotificationItem(notification: MyNotification) {
    OutlinedCard {
        Text(text = notification.title)
        Text(text = notification.packageName)
        Text(text = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(notification.postTime))
    }
}
```

in the other activity:

```
try {
                myDataset.add(MyNotification(sbn))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.v(thisTag, "An error occurred adding MyNotification in myDataset.")
            }
```

I want to specify that the try function succeeds.

I expected to see the LazyList changes in real when the dataset changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in your code.

First, you should not perform any IO operations on main thread which you're doing currently by reading from database. You should use `ViewModel` in which you should read your database and have a property to hold your list.

Second, you don't need to pass `MutableList<MyNotification>` to `@Composable` just pass `List<MyNotification>`. Also, remove this line `val notifications = remember { dataset }`. And use `key` parameter of `items` in `LazyColumn`.